# After generating a new component, doesn't automatically import app.module.ts and when manually put it in, it doesn't read

Tags: angular

After generating a new component, it doesn't give an error but it doesn't automatically import app.module.ts and when manually put it in, it doesn't read how to fix it en angular v17
I'm working on an angular project at the beginning,
the components will be automatically imported to the app-module and will work,
But then I see that there are components that haven't been added that I've tried to put them in manually,
but they don't always work, they tell me that this component is not imported into the app-module,
So I created another project and first moved the old component to the new one,
But after moving the old file to the new one,
I encounter the same problem when I create new components that are not added to the application module
And even the components that I had a problem with the old project weren't added to the new project

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project with angular 17, you won’t have any modules in your project, we have the [standalone configuration as the default](https://blog.angular.io/introducing-angular-v17-4d7033312e4b)

So Angular 17 generate an angular application which is standalone API, there is no module.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct. Since Angular 17, by default you don't need to import anything into the module. All the necessary modules and components are imported directly into the components, but there is the `standalone: true` option by default. But if you want it to be like in the old versions, you can always turn it to false.